# VBA throwing Out Of Memory error when copying ranges by value

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

I am working on processing a fairy modest table (around 7k rows) in Excel and encountered an error while simply copying data from one place to another in different files.
The copying is done via the command

`destCol.value = sourceCol.value`

I made sure that both ranges have matching sizes and take just the data, not the entire column.

I am seeing a "out of memory" error on this line when the looping through columns come to a particular column that was recently added. The new column is a text column which is mostly empty, but can have sometimes up to 2k chars. What seems strange is that the task manager does not show a spike in memory usage, so I think maybe some temporary array for copying is too large for the operation to succeed?

Is there a way I can view how much memory is being taken up by the column in memory and what is the memory limit, why does that error occur in this example?

I can copy the range using the copy and pasteSpecial xlPasteValues command, but I would hope to understand what is happening in this case. (I would have hoped copying a 6k row by 1 col range would be doable)

EDIT: I have determined that the problem occurs only when copying between two files, if I try to copy between two columns in the same file there error does not appear.
What's more I tried to read that into two lines...

```
arr = sourceCol.value
destCol.value = arr
```

... and when the issue appeared on the second line I tried changing the destCol to be a (appropriately sized) range on a entirely new sheet. The "Out of memory" error popped, but the column was partially copied over - after about 1920 rows pasted which had 516k chars combined.

Comment: Is the issue repeatable, on another computer?

Comment: Yes, this was reported to me from spreadsheet user and also happens on my and a colleagues spreadsheet. We've been reducing the number of rows to not have the erorr anymore, but I don't get the impression we all have the same number that works for that.

Comment: Please, (just for testing) try `destCol.value2 = sourceCol.value2`...

Comment: Only now got a chance to revisit:The `destCol.value2 = sourceCol.value2` returns the same "Out of memory" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had same issue (got to this question hoping for an answer...)

comments here helped find my issue:
I found the problem line by realizing the data did copy up to the problem cell as your original post mentions

I had a column formatted as date with a value of -29 that somehow got in, as soon as i removed that anomalous value everything started working no problem

i believe that it is actually getting some sort of crazy "type mismatch" error but not able articulate the correct error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And now your answer made me revisit my data and finally (duh) notice that the value that is not copied and the "out of memory" error leaves is a text field beginning with an "-" sign. When I removed it from the source data the entire column is copied over without an issue. Seems like Excel attempts to put that string beginning with "-" as a formula and somewhere along the way ends up with that error.

Comment: The out of memory error is a real red herring

Answer (score 0):

I've previously seen this thrown when a cell holds too many characters. It sounds like this shouldn't be the case for you but I can think of a way for it to happen.

I am sorry I do not have enough reputation to comment, or I would have commented this question before typing out an answer, but are the ranges across two different files? Perhaps even a .CSV to.XLSX?

If the delimiter is different between the files, it is possible that VBA attempts to shove the entire CSV file into the first cell of your destination range. It would happen if the CSV delimiter is not recogniced by your excel sheet.

This can happen due to regional settings, for instance here in Denmark our CSV files default to semicolon as delimiter instead of commma. So if I did the same as you are doing without a care for the delimiter I would get the same error. If you live in a place where comma is used to separate decimals and dots are used for separating thousands, then you are likely in the same boat as me, and need to change these settings in excel!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the hint, I've just checked that the file does actually occur between two files! They're both .xlsx (well, one .xlsm and .xlsx), but when I tried to copy the values between two column on the same sheet the error did not pop up.